# Codeigniter Nested Database Data

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I google and google and read 100000 tutorials but i think this is inposible to do in codeigniter on model, controller and views.

Am tring to show my database records like this :

```
Default Category
   |----- Sub category
          | ----One more category
               |----- Somthing else
```

I try with **LFT** and **RGT** cols but i realy dont much understand that concept.

I read this and try that function to optimize in Codeigniter model but that only work in model.
http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

I now have simple db sheme : Categories with cols id, parent_id, title

Any1 can give me one simple example... Please

Thanks

Comment: you need to use nested `foreach()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the follow basic table structure:

- id
- parent_id
- name

You need to do a nested loop.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE parent_id = 0; # First level
SELECT * FROM table WHERE parent_id = ?; # Subsequent levels
```

Normally you would then build this into an object in your model which would return something like an array with children in it.  We would normally do this with a function that calls itself and returns an object that we append to the previous object.  Watch out with recursive functions though, they have a tendency to go wrong on you!

Hope that helps.